# When using the ldd command on a directory, how do I only show dynamically linked executables?

Tags: linux, shell

for example, if I do:

```
$ ldd /bin/*
```

I get unwanted output, such as:

```
/bin/zless:
    not a dynamic executable
```

How would I go about removing those unwanted outputs from ldd?

Answer (score 0):

```
file /bin/* | awk -F: '$2 ~ "dynamically linked" {print $1}' | xargs ldd
```

`file` will tell you which files are dynamically linked executables. You can filter on its output and pass the matching file names to `ldd` with `xargs`.

To be extra robust, it'd be good to use NUL characters as separators in all of the commands. That way you can handle file names with unusual characters like `:` and `\n`.

```
file -0 /bin/* | awk -F'\0' -vORS='\0' '$2 ~ "dynamically linked" {print $1}' | xargs -0 ldd
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!


Instead of /bin/*, what if I wanted to search all directories starting from the root?


I tried file / | awk but that doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: `find / -type f -exec file -0 {} + | awk ...`